# I need help using \multicol (or other) to recreate this document

Tags: enumerate, multicol, columns

I am converting some old materials into TeX files, and the goal is to preserve their visuals as much as possible. This seems to be a \multicols kind of a thing to do, but I can't really figure out how to start forcing the spacing to be where I need. Can anyone help me figure out how to template/design this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please, show us, what you try so far. We haven't any information about your document ...

Comment: I'm sorry, perhaps I should have posted or tagged it differently. I don't have much of anything so far, as I'm unusually stumped about how to approach this at all. I thought about trying to do 2-columns INSIDE another 2-columns, but even if that worked there would need to be a lot of customization of the margins that I don't know how to do. I'd also still love to run enumerate to populate a column, and don't know if that would work inside. So, I guess I was researching if anybody had a clever idea of how to design this. Should I have posted it differently then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on [@JohnKormylo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/653008/31283), I'd probably create a custom list for this using combination of `\newlist` and `\setlist` (from [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)). If you prefer only a part of you document to be of two-columns, you could insert the list inside the `multicols` environments (from [multicol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package).

This is MWE with some dummy text and a part of the list

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}   % only for dummy text

\newlength\customlen \setlength\customlen{2cm}
\newlist{problemanswer}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[problemanswer]{
    itemindent=\customlen,
    labelwidth=\customlen,
    leftmargin=0pt,
    labelsep=0pt,
    parsep=3pt,
    itemsep=0pt,
    topsep=0pt,
    align=left,
}
\setlist[problemanswer,1]{label=\arabic*}
\setlist[problemanswer,2]{label*=\space\alph*, before=\stepcounter{problemansweri}}


\begin{document}
\kant[1]

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    {\Large Defining New Symbols}
    
    \vspace{\baselineskip}%
    \makebox[\customlen][l]{\textbf{Problem}}\textbf{Answer}

    \begin{problemanswer}
        \item 32
        \item 77
        \item 5
        \item 140
        \item \(10y + Y^2\)
        \item \(16x + 64\)
        \item \(2xy + y^2\)
        \begin{problemanswer}
            \item Answers may vary:
            \item No
        \end{problemanswer}
        \begin{problemanswer}
            \item 32
            \item 35
            \item \(x \& y = x + xy\)
            \item Yes
            \item and so one ...
        \end{problemanswer}
        \item etc. ...
        \item 32
        \item 77
        \item 5
        \item 140
        \item \(10y + Y^2\)
        \item \(16x + 64\)
        \item \(2xy + y^2\)
        \begin{problemanswer}
            \item Answers may vary:
            \item No
        \end{problemanswer}
        \begin{problemanswer}
            \item 32
            \item 35
            \item \(x \& y = x + xy\)
            \item Yes
            \item and so one ...
        \end{problemanswer}
        \item etc. ...
    \end{problemanswer}
    \raggedcolumns
\end{multicols}

\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh that's like perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This uses `enumerate` with `enumitem`.  I'm only showing a couple of `\item`s, but `itemize` **will** split over columns.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\section*{Defining New Symbols}

\begin{enumerate}[labelwidth=1in, itemindent=!, align=left]
  \item[\textbf{Problem}]\textbf{Answer}
    \item 32
    \item \ref{unknown}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```